# Convert Java HmacMD5 function to VB6

Tags: java, vb6, md5, hmac

I'm working on a windows app, and need to use some auth function from some previous java code. I have access to the Java source but still can't seem to get it right. Probably because of my limited knowledge of cryptography.

The Java functions I need to convert are :

```
public String getHMACHash(String SharedSecretKey, String TextToHash) {
    return base64EncodedStringFromBytes(hmacMD5(SharedSecretKey, TextToHash));
}

private String base64EncodedStringFromBytes(byte[] bArr) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(bArr, 2);
}


public byte[] hmacMD5(String SharedSecretKey, String TextToHash) {
    byte[] bArr = null;
    try {
        Mac instance = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
        instance.init(new SecretKeySpec(SharedSecretKey.getBytes(), "HmacMD5"));
        bArr = instance.doFinal(TextToHash.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.m8401e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e2) {
        Log.m8401e(TAG, e2.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return bArr;
}
```

so when inputting the values :

```
SharedSecretKey = "497n9x98jK06gf7S3T7wJ2k455Qm192Q"
TextToHash = "1502322764327/customerservice.svc/buybackcartPOST8e802a045c1e60e"
```

the Hash generated is :

```
pOZNkg077OdvhyeMMPIX2w==
```

Try as I might I can't get near to the hash key using the same values in VB6. I have tried a few different methods to create the hash :

```
Private Function hash_HMACMD5(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal 
sSharedSecretKey As String)

Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
Dim TextToHash() As Byte
Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5")

 TextToHash = asc.Getbytes_4(sTextToHash)
 SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(sSharedSecretKey)
 enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

 Dim bytes() As Byte
 bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
 hash_HMACMD5 = Base64Encode(bytes)

 Set asc = Nothing
 Set enc = Nothing

 End Function
```

So, I was hoping someone out there might be able to point me in the right direction ?

Thanks In advance for any help.

Potman100

I've traced all the code through, and I can't see any thing that would indicate something different is going on. As mentioned below, there is a import line

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

The call to create the hash is :

```
String hMACHash = new MASecurity().getHMACHash(str, str2);
```

MASecurity Class is :

```
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MASecurity {
private static final String TAG = "MASecurity";

public String getHMACHash(String str, String str2) {
    return base64EncodedStringFromBytes(hmacMD5(str, str2));
}

private String base64EncodedStringFromBytes(byte[] bArr) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(bArr, 2);
}

public byte[] hmacMD5(String str, String str2) {
    byte[] bArr = null;
    try {
        Mac instance = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
        instance.init(new SecretKeySpec(str.getBytes(), "HmacMD5"));
        bArr = instance.doFinal(str2.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        MALog.m8401e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e2) {
        MALog.m8401e(TAG, e2.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return bArr;
}
```

The input values are correct, as they are logged whilst the app is running.

Hope this helps ??

Comment: What is `str1` and what is `str2`. Please use meaningful variable names like "text" and "secretKey" like you did in the VB, so people can follow and understand your code.

Comment: Hi, I just added the code the way it was in the old Java code, 

str = SharedKey
str2 = TextToHash

I will update the code above.

Comment: From VB6 I get `0MQLYL4A9fH2+o2Pb0PYJw==` and from Java I get the same: https://ideone.com/yHmaoQ - the only difference is I used `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bArr)` as you have not stated what the `Base64` type is in your code.  So either the encoding routine your using is doing something unexpected or `pOZNkg077OdvhyeMMPIX2w==` is the hash for a different set of inputs.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your help, I noticed in the code an import :

    import android.util.Base64;

Could this be causing the issue ?

Comment: I've some more info above.

Comment: Just one other thing I noticed, the line : Base64.encodeToString(bArr, 2);, looking at the documentation for android.util.Base64, the 2 represents the  position within the input array at which to start, is this were its going wrong ?

Comment: I believe the `2` is an unfortunate use of a magic number instead of the named constant for the "no wrap" flag.  One more reason why magic numbers are poor technique.

Comment: Thanks Bob, developing mainly in VB6 I'm not to used to over loaded functions and there are 2 for Base64.encodeToString as you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex K., seems the Java code was adding more data to one of the params which the debugging I did missed, one I added the extra data it creates a valid hash.